# Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC Hide / Unhide various Grid Columns based on viewport width

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, telerik-mvc

I've got a rather wide (1200+px) Telerik Grid in Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC in Razor Syntax and I want to be able to hide / unhide certain columns based on the width of the end user's viewport in their browser.  Is this possible?

My wish would be to have 3 columns appear that are otherwise set to .Hidden(true) if viewport width was >1024px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to use media queries and the technique of responsive design.

The basic principle would be to render all columns so they are all emitted in the HTML (i.e. set Hidden to false on all columns) and then use media queries in the CSS to show/hide the appropriate columns based on the viewport width.

I'm not sure of the exact markup that the Telerik grid emits, but I've created a jsfiddle that demonstrates the concept with a basic HTML table here: http://jsfiddle.net/peRq2/

HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th>Header</th>
        <th class="wide">Header (wide)</th>
        <th class="wide">Header (wide)</th>
        <th class="wide">Header (wide)</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Value</td>
            <td>Value</td>
            <td>Value</td>
            <td class="wide">Value</td>
            <td class="wide">Value</td>
            <td class="wide">Value</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Value</td>
            <td>Value</td>
            <td>Value</td>
            <td class="wide">Value</td>
            <td class="wide">Value</td>
            <td class="wide">Value</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS3 (with the media query based on a width of 600px - you can change to 1200px):

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {

.wide {
    display: none;
}

}
```

The idea is that the `th`s and `td`s marked up with the `wide` class are hidden when the viewport is less than 600px. Try changing the width of the result pane on the jsfiddle to see the result of the media query at work.

One thing to note is the browser compatibility of media queries (basically IE9 and above and all other modern browsers): http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries - there's also more here: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries

Hope this gives you some inspiration!

Comment: Thanks, Alistair. My only issue now is how to add classes to telerik. It doesn't look like html Attributes to allowed

Comment: I was able to add HtmlAttributes and was able to get the columns to show.  My issue with this implementation, though is that the row data is now blank for those expanded columns. Anyone know how to solve this?